# How can i/can i type this code in only one line?

Tags: python, calculator

I made a really simple calculator with this code:

```
while True:
    calc_input = input("enter calculation")
    print(f"{calc_input} = {eval(calc_input)}")
```

Me, and my friend (We both are new in programming) tried to convert this to a one line code, but we failed. I need an understandable explanation of how can i type this code in one line (or can i).
(I don't need the same code in one line, any code in one line that can do the same job as my code would be okay for me.)

Comment: Are you looking for list comprehension? Why do you want to put this on one line? It looks perfectly fine like this

Comment: I think you shouldn't look so much for short code, but more for readable code.

Comment: Why do you want to "convert this to a one line code"?

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of answering the question, this should work:

```
while True: print(f"{(calc_input := input("enter calculation")} = {eval(calc_input)}")
```

Or, by just using `print`'s var-arg behavior:

```
while True: print((calc_input := input("enter calculation")), '=', eval(calc_input))
```

`:=` is like `=`, but it's an expression, so it can be used anywhere.

For the love of God though, please don't do this. This may be nice if you're code-golfing or something, but it fails the readability test. This code over several lines is fine.

Comment: my goal is just to learn how to do it. im not gonna use it